# Identify this 80's styletelevision show with witches and a kid who transforms into a vehicle

Tags: episode-identification, story-identification

I remember as a kid seeing a show that stuck with me for some reason, though the memory is vague enough that it might have simply been a dream, or an amalgamation of existing shows. The elements I remember (in no particular order) were:

1) Some kids on the run from police, one transforms into a car (or maybe a motorcycle), goes over a jump on a narrow road, evading police. The setting was at night, outside of some kind of warehouse/club (think the beginning of the music video to *Smooth Criminal*). Also reminded me of the alleyway scene in *Equilibrium*. Car/cycle was sporty, either red or black.

2) Two of the kids (brother/sister?) find a witches lair, peering in from above while the witch cannot see them. Spider motifs everywhere within the lair, which amounts to a medium dirt cave dug vertically. The witch is unaware of their presence, but danger is still present (suspenseful music).

I want to identify the kids in both situations as the same, but am unsure whether this actually exists or not. Does anybody know what this (or either component) might be from?

Comment: When were you a kid (help us narrow down a time frame)? Was it live-action, animated, cg? What country were you in? Did it seem to be foreign (re-dubbed/subtitled)?

Comment: No subtitles. Could have been animated, but could just as easily have been live-action (terrible kid memory). I saw it sometime during the nineties, but it seemed stylistically 80's. This was in the United States.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember an 80s cartoon called *Turbo Teen* about a boy who turns into a car.

No Wikipedia page, but it's listed at 9:30AM in [ABC 1984 Saturday morning cartoons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984%E2%80%931985_United_States_network_television_schedule_%28Saturday_morning%29).

Comment: The car escape part possessed some of the feel of both Turbo Teen and Knight Rider, but I haven't seen enough of either to place it as one, the other, or something else entirely.

Comment: Having watched some of this show now, it seems the most likely candidate. No concrete confirmation yet, but working on it.

Comment: After watching almost the entire season of the show that exists, I think you're on it with Turbo Teen. I'll chalk up the other piece to fanciful imagination, unless someone can find it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I remember as a child I thought the title was "Turbo Team" because the three kids work together. The word "teen" didn't mean anything to me at age 6.

Comment: Didn't he turn into the car when he got hot or something and back to a boy when he got wet?

Comment: Something like that. I tried watching some and it didn't hold my attention. Same with most of my childhood favs: He-Man, Voltron. Muppet Babies is still good, though.